# How can I change previously entered username in Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1?

Tags: vpn, login

Yesterday I installed and launched Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1 (on Windows 10). I entered server name, port, pressed "Connect" button, entered Login and Password. Today I want to connect with another login. But after I click "Connect" button the form appears with a disabled login field, so I can't change it.

How can I change the previously entered username in Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client?